# Не начинается установка Linux с загрузочной флешки

Tags: linux, установка, bios

Пытаюсь установить Linux дистрибутив рядом с Windows 10 с загрузочной флешки. Однако после перезагрузки компьютера вместо предложения установки Linux появляется консоль grub. Искал в сети данный вопрос, говорят, что скорее всего `secure boot` находится в режиме enabled и его нужно поменять на disabled. Но оказалось, что у меня итак стоит disabled. Какие предложения есть ?

Comment: Какой дистр ставите? Сколько хардов физических стоит? Куда grub заливаете?

Comment: Возможно нужно выбрать в BIOS раздел с которого начать загрузку.

Comment: @Bleser Linux mint. Один ssd накопитель. С grub'ом ничего не делал (сам поставился из скачанного iso).

Comment: @Bleser раздел ? приоритеты устройств ? Да, там стоит сначала флешка - с этим все нормально.

Comment: Извините сразу не увидел что у вас просто с флешки не запускается установка ^_^.  


На флешку чем образ записываете? Попробуйте unetbootin или rufus. Лично у меня никогда не было проблем с программой rufus.

Comment: @Bleser через unetbootin. Пробую rufus сейчас. я поставил необязательную галочку над проверкой на плохие блоки и он нашел на флешке 200 плохих блоков. Пропустить это ?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/71593/discussion-between-bleser-and-).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В общем попробую оформить свои коменты в виде ответа.

Если у вас при попытке установить дистрибутив Linux Mint или любой другой не происходит корректного запуска с флешки скорее всего криво записался образ.
Для записи образа на флешку можно использовать следующие программы (самый простой способ):

- [Rufus](http://rufus.akeo.ie/?locale) - *стоит попробовать в первую очередь*
- [UNetbootin](https://unetbootin.github.io)

Так же возможно что вы используете битый образ или ваша флешка доживает последние дни.